# Extend C code to dynamically allocate a 3D array

Tags: c, arrays, 3d, malloc

I want to dynamically allocate a 3D array based on the following code which creates a 2D array, any suggestions would be very helpful:

```
void** malloc_2d (size_t nrows, size_t ncols, int elementsize) {
size_t i;
void ** ptr;

if ( (ptr = (void**)malloc(nrows * sizeof(void *))) == NULL ) {

  fprintf(stderr, "malloc_2d: out of memory\n");

  exit(1);

}


 if ( (ptr[0] = malloc(nrows * ncols * elementsize)) == NULL ) {

  fprintf(stderr, "malloc_2d: out of memory\n");

  exit(1);

 }

for (i=1; i<nrows; i++) 

  ptr[i] = (char*)ptr[0] + i * ncols * elementsize;

 return ptr;
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So I declared void *** ptr; and added a ptr[1] = malloc....